# Multiple sessions created for every request in express.js

Tags: session, redis, express-session

The issue I'm describing here it's happening in my local development machine, without any proxy between browser requests and the apps. 
I have several Node.js microservices which share the same technologies used to manage sessions:

- The latest version of Express
- [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#options) for session management

The usual flow sees the user doing login in the authentication app and then being redirected to the frontend (a React app), which performs CORS requests to a backend microservice, which is running a GraphQL server.
This issue is very similar to [the one described here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/212), even if I have a slightly different configuration (static route just in the auth app and used before session definition and `false` to both `resave` and `saveUninitialized` options).

Both auth/backend apps have this configuration:

```
const sessionOptions = {
    store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        disableTTL: true,
    }),
    secret: "123",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: false,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
        domain: config.cookie.domain,
        sameSite: config.cookie.sameSite,
        maxAge: toTime(config.cookie.maxAge).ms(),
        secure: config.cookie.secure,
    },
};
app.use(session(sessionOptions));

// Configure passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The backend app has the additional CORS config:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "frontend_url",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
}));
```

Initial Redis status:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS "*"
(empty list or set)
```

I go to the login page and a session is created:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS "*"
1) "sess:H5VTTBiNSQqu0Fsp2ZfSH2wBZtL4XEZh"
```

I do log in, the session is still one until I get redirected to my React application and then I get six new sessions:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS "*"
1) "sess:NNWse-sp51fVRf6rlnsFpMlZO1gkPgYC"
2) "sess:ofQhH0iBbZOvsJBYMxwHjLL0DKxuFKfS"
3) "sess:XxsTGSoANPE5-fPYbwLmoCgvDho0NTnk"
4) "sess:9wFDQ3_RibJyEXEmJ_8gCxfnak4Uh0yP"
5) "sess:8khC8fgbtO53mJNilMhp88toIcsizxea"
6) "sess:jfQBWogefBr75IgZ5GykSgd5d3t3Mt_D"
7) "sess:H5VTTBiNSQqu0Fsp2ZfSH2wBZtL4XEZh"
```

Whatever link I click, it raises their number to 16, and so on. I cannot spot any request to my backend which isn't sending the session cookie but OPTION pre-flight requests. So I tried to use [my own configuration instead than CORS module](https://gist.github.com/cuppster/2344435), but nothing changed.
If I log out, obviously just the original session that matched my session cookie is deleted from Redis, the rest (since I've disabled TTL to have "permanent" sessions) just dangle there.
It's also obvious that I don't want Redis to be filled with useless sessions, but I cannot find what could be the real issue.
Any advice?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I've noticed a different behavior if I try to modify `genid` function with something customized:

- for the authentication service, I return `null` if I don't have `req.body.username` defined (`${req.body.username}_${uuidv4()}`).
- for the backend service I just return `null` everytime.

The first request to the auth service raises an exception `invalid csrf`, because probably it cannot be found inside Redis, since `genid` is returning null now. The second request (assuming that you use the same email as before and that logging in is successful), leads me to the frontend, and this time I can see just one session being created. 
Obviously, this isn't a correct flow, but anyway it's strange that it's creating just one session in Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I discovered some requests sent to my auth service which didn't set the session cookie, for some paths it wasn't even supposed to be used.
So I defined those paths related to session with:

```js
const sessionPaths = ['/path1', '/path2', ...];
app.use(sessionPaths, session(sessionOptions));
app.use(sessionPaths, passport.initialize());
app.use(sessionPaths, passport.session());
app.use(sessionPaths, csrf());
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is completely solved but given the order of how you lay it out, you might have the cors handler after the session handler. As the preflight requests come in a session is possibly being created for each of those as there is no session cookie or credentials being sent. The simple fix is to move the cors handler above the session handler.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It solved my issue.

For those looking for an answer, things that worked for me are:

1. Set `saveUninitialized: false,`
2. Make sure you are passing `credentials: true` for all your requests coming from frontend
3. cors() middleware to be placed before session middleware

Answer (score 0):

I had run in to the same issue a few days back! I have set up my repo and sharing my link to the same! It works perfect! Do check it out.

https://github.com/ritwbanerjee/angular-node-seed

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see anything particularly different from my use case, so I cannot understand why I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: Can you please share the link to your repo so that we can look into your middleware configurations

Comment: Hi Ritwik, no worries, in the end, I've found some routes that were called without passing the cookie, so I excluded them from session management since I use a token-based authorization system there.

Answer (score 0):

setting `saveUninitialized` to `false` worked for me!

```
var app = express()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  ...
}));
```

[express-session middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)